# Can I implement deep learning models in my laptop with intel hd graphics

Tags: gpu, deep-learning, keras

I am currently doing a project on deep learning for my masters degree. I wanted to install keras library, so when I started installing Theano and tensorflow i saw that i have to install CUDA. But my laptop comes with intel hd graphics. So my question is will it work if i install them anyway.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install and use keras without cuda, but you can't get gpu accelerating with intel hd graphics.

If you use Theano as keras' backend, first install Theano:

```
# for python2
pip install theano
# for python3
pip3 install theano
```

Then set ~/.theanorc file like this:

```
[global]
floatX = float32
device = cpu
allow_gc = True

[blas]
ldflags = -lopenblas
```

If you use TensorFlow as keras' backend, just install the CPU version of TensorFlow.

```
# for python2.7
pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
# for python3.4
pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-cp34-cp34m-linux_x86_64.whl
# for python3.5
pip3 install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Then install keras:

```
# for python2
pip install keras
# for python3
pip3 install keras
```

Comment: @Alapan So, was it any better than CPU when you tested it on integrated card without cuda?

Comment: @MarkSeygan: That makes no sense. The choice is between CPU and CUDA. Hence, (not CUDA) means CPU.

Answer (score 9):

Edit:
As of now, you can directly use OpenCL based clDNN  (https://github.com/01org/clDNN) instead of using OpenVX, in order to perform Deep Learning inference on Intel Graphics. You will have to do the training on a powerful GPU like Nvidia or AMD and use the pre-trained model and use it in clDNN.

You can start using Intel's Computer Vision SDK (https://software.intel.com/en-us/computer-vision-sdk) in order to write Deep Learning Applications using OpenCV or OpenVX.

OpenVX (https://www.khronos.org/openvx/) programming model allows you to write simple Neural Network pipelines using the following SPEC (https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenVX/extensions/neural_network/html/)

Alternatively you can use Model Optimizer that converts Caffe/TensorFlow model into OpenVX, and you can accelerate the OpenVX Neural Network graph on Intel Integrated HD Graphics.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your last paragraph? What is Model Optimizer? how do I convert to OpenVX? can it be doe with Python? can I train using Python?

Comment: @Eran ModelOptimizer is part of Intel's OpenVINO toolkit. It can read various models (caffe, TF, onnx, etc) and do a bunch of optimizations, from discarding training-only things such as dropout-layers to cutting away unused parts of the net (0-weights, including setting almost-0-values to 0) or changing to 16bit precision to speed up inference, and, of course, use intel-specific HW (GPU, VPU, FPGA)

Answer (score 2):

Their is a [PlaidML](https://github.com/plaidml/plaidml) with that you train deep learning model on Intel and AMD gpu.