# Getting permission denied error while installing tensorflow and keras

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, permission-denied

After following the steps from my previously asked question [Can I implement deep learning models in my laptop with intel hd graphics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340461/can-i-implement-deep-learning-models-in-my-laptop-with-intel-hd-graphics/41341085#41341085)
I am getting a permission denied error while installing tensorflow

[image: error13]

What can I do to install tensorflow and keras without getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pip3 is trying to access `/usr/bin/` for which you need superuser rights. Try

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade ...
```

Comment: have a look at @mrry's answer too.

Comment: @DragonKnight: Please open a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that TensorFlow depends on a newer version of the `setuptools` package than you have installed. As [Maximilian points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41366488/3574081), `pip` needs root access to upgrade `setuptools` and install TensorFlow and Keras in your machine's Python distribution. You can either use `sudo` as he suggests, or it may be safer to [install TensorFlow into a Virtualenv](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup#virtualenv_installation). For example, to create a Virtualenv in the directory `~/tensorflow`, execute the following commands:

```
$ sudo pip install virtualenv
$ virtualenv --system-site-packages ~/tensorflow
$ cd ~/tensorflow
$ source bin/activate
$ pip install https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/linux/cpu/tensorflow-0.12.0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
```