# How to train a neural network using intel integrated graphics

Tags: neural-network, gpu, intel

My computer has a `Intel Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller`. I want to train a neural network using the integrated graphics. There is no need for speed-up. What should I do?

Comment: Which library are you using to train your neural network?

Comment: I used Keras to train my NN on CPU before

Answer (score 1):

Since Keras use Tensorflow under the hood Tensorflow's GPU support needs Nvidia Cuda and CuDNN packages installed. For GPU accelerated training you will need a dedicated GPU. Intel onboard graphics can't be used for that purpose.

You can check the support https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu

Comment: How can I achieve that purpose？ Use another library or something else?

Comment: I was searching for the same and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41340461/can-i-implement-deep-learning-models-in-my-laptop-with-intel-hd-graphics